# Ex-EEA family member biometric card holder after Brexit

Tags: immigration, eu, residency, brexit, turkish-citizens

After a divorce with an EU national , Ive applied to retain my rights for residence and been granted a 5 year valid Biometric Residence card by UK Home office.

The card I was sent is a residence card for a family member of a union citizen and the type of permit is FAMILY MEMBER-EU RESIDENCE.

Based on Home Office’s letter, I was granted this residence card based on the fact that I had been a family member even though I’m no longer a family member.

My card expires on 2023. I’m a Turkish citizen and a Turkish passport holder . However because of the type of Residence Card I have, do I need to apply for a pre-settlement before Brexit just like any other EU citizens.

I have been and working living in the UK here since Jan 2015 and Turkey is not in EU or EEA.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have ‘retained right of residence’ and therefore you need to apply https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/not-EU-EEA-Swiss-citizen